# Weird PHP date behavior when trying to get last day of last month

Tags: php, function, date

I've just noticed that PHP date function acts weird, can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

Following code displays same results

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-t');
// Outputs last day of this month: 2016-03-31
echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime("-1 month"));
// For some reason outputs the same: 2016-03-31
echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime("+1 month"));
// Outputs 2016-05-31
```

It might be just me being stupid, but could someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: This is all documented on the GNU page PHP docs clearly links to too. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/shishi/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings): `The fuzz in units can cause problems with relative items. For example, ‘2003-07-31 -1 month’ might evaluate to 2003-07-01, because 2003-06-31 is an invalid date. `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `t` in your `date('Y-m-t')` call you're referring to:

> `t` - Number of days in the given month

If you tried `Y-m-d` you'd figure out that it's 2 different dates:

```
<?php

var_dump( date('Y-m-d') );
var_dump( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month') ) );
```

> string(10) "`2016-03-31`"
>   string(10) "`2016-03-02`"

To fix this issue you can use the `strtotime` format `last day of last month`:

```
<?php

var_dump( date('Y-m-d') );
var_dump( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month') ) );
```

which results in:

> string(10) "`2016-03-31`"
>   string(10) "`2016-02-29`"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I've thought - it's just me being stupid :)

Comment: And what you can do if you want to use `\DateTime()`  sub with `\DateInterval('P1M')`? Result will be the same like `-1 month` or `last month`.

Answer (score 6):

Try `date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month"))`, what does that display? March 2nd. Why? Because February 31st doesn't exist, and PHP does date rollover math.

The basic issue is that "minus one month" is very vaguely and ill defined. What *should* happen when that lands on dates like "February 31st"? There's no good or correct answer. Don't leave it up to PHP to decide the outcome. Explicitly deduct one month from the *first* of a month if you expect a defined outcome.